# Difference between "href" and "ng-href" in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I've used both `href` and `ng-href` and I couldn't see the difference between them.

Why does Angular have the `ng-href` attribute, and when should I use it?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[From the documentation:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)

> Using Angular markup like `{{hash}}` in an href attribute will make the link go to the wrong URL if the user clicks it before Angular has a chance to replace the `{{hash}}` markup with its value. Until Angular replaces the markup the link will be broken and will most likely return a 404 error. The `ngHref` directive solves this problem.

Effectively, the only place you're using it is for links in which you need to rely on a value provided to the DOM by Angular.  If you do not require Angular for a part of that link, or you don't plan on using Angular to generate that link, then you do not need to use `ngHref`.

Answer (score 14):

If you need to bind values from your model you use the directive. For example:

```
<div ng-init="address='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37467603'">

  <a ng-href="{{address}}">Dynamic link</a>

  <br/>

  Change the link dynamically: <input type="text" ng-model="address">

</div>
```

In the example above, the value of `address` is programmatically bound to the value in the input text box, which you can change.

If you don't need to be dynamic (i.e. react to a change in the model's state), then you can simply stay with `href`:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37467603"/>Static link</a>
```

Comment: You cant be dynamic with href?

Comment: @LiamAppleyard read Makoto's explanation - Dynamic here probably means substituting the address in rather than just a string.

Comment: While this answer has correct info, it does not answer the question. Also, you can use `herf={{address}}` for dynamic too but you have to understand that the link will not be correct until Angular has resolved it; which makes no difference if the link is hidden until Angular has resolved it.