# does not load my page using ngroute with parameter in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I'm something new in angularjs and I have a page that redirects to another with a parameter id, but this does not load anything, I do not know what is wrong.

This is the home.html where I call the url with the parameter

```html
 <div class='card_actions'>
     <a href="#/post/{{id}}" class="btn-btn--m btn--blue btn--flat" lx-ripple>Leer mas
     </a>
 </div>
```

This is the controller where I assign the addresses with the id parameter
app.js

```js
var app = angular.module('FinalApp',['ngResource','lumx','ngRoute'])
app.config(["$routeProvider","$locationProvider",function(route,location){
    location.hashPrefix('');
    route
        .when('/',{
            controller: 'MainController',
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
        })
        .when('/post/:id',{
            controller: 'PostController',
            templateUrl: 'templates/post.html' 
        })
         .otherwise("/");
}]);
```

This is the controller of the post.html page

```js
app.controller('PostController',function($scope,$resource,$routeParams){

    Post = $resource('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/id',{id:'@id'});
    $scope.post = Post.get({id:$routeParams.id});

});
```

This is the page that I want to load
post.html

```html
<div class='card-top-space'>
    <div class='p+' style="background-color: red">
        <strong class='fs-headline display-block tc-red-900'>
            {{post.title}}
        </strong>
        <div class='paragrah fs-body-1 mt+'>
            {{post.body}}
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: Where does the code assign a value to `$scope.id`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have angular code in your `href`, you need to use `ngHref` instead. You have `{{id}}` in your href.

Try this in your **home.html**

```
<div class='card_actions'>
  <a ng-href="#/post/{{id}}" class="btn-btn--m btn--blue btn--flat" lx-ripple>Leer mas</a>
</div>
```

See [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) for the documentation on `ngHref`

Answer (score 0):

Your `href` cannot process the `{{id}}` in the route. This is because it is an [AngularJS expression](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_expressions.asp). If you want an `anchor tag`(`<a>`) whose route has an angular expression you need use something called the `ng-href` instead of the `href`.

You can refer to [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37467603/difference-between-href-and-ng-href-in-angularjs) to understand it better.

Hence inside your **home.html**:

```
 <a ng-href="#/post/{{id}}" class="btn-btn--m btn--blue btn--flat" lx-ripple>Leer mas
 </a>
```

Hope this helps.